# How to get the HTML code of a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, html, google-sheets

I have styled text with multiple links within a single cell in this [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18V4ucCooMCLotSt0TRynGRs4vpDbVxqV_OZsauE9KVg/edit?usp=sharing) (or see linked image below) that I would like to get the HTML code for.

If I manually download the sheet as "Web page (.html zipped)" this gives me the html code I am looking for but I would like a way to either get this html code in a python script or into another cell of the sheet using a google sheets formula or google sheets script. For example,the desired output for the styled text currently in the cell is shown below:

```html
<br/>Hi there, <br/><br/>Great news \xe2\x80\x94 the new Telnyx API is now officially out of beta and ready for action. Designed for fast, seamless integration and effortless scaling, the new API comes with robust documentation for every use case. So, whether you\xe2\x80\x99re scaling voice connections with SIP trunking, building conferencing capabilities, or an IVR system \xe2\x80\x94 you\xe2\x80\x99ll be able to find a step-by-step guide with handy code snippets to help you get the job done.<br/><br/>The new Telnyx API includes five SDK\xe2\x80\x99s \xe2\x80\x94 Python, Node, Ruby, PHP and .NET, with more coming soon. This, along with consistent API formatting and behaviour means a faster, more streamlined go-to-market. <br/><br/><span style="font-weight:bold;">How do I make the switch?<br/></span><br/>1. step 1<br/>2. step 2<br/>3. step 3<br/><br/>As a user of API v1, you\xe2\x80\x99ll continue to <span style="font-style:italic;">receive</span> the same support you do now. But, to reap the benefits of a faster and easier-to-use API we do recommend switching to the new version when you\xe2\x80\x99re ready. <br/>To help make sure the switch is risk and hassle free, we\xe2\x80\x99ve put together a simple <span style="text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;color:#1155cc;"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/development/api-v1-to-v2-migration-guides/call-control&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1590777936749000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHQNNxgH4SnH0vAQiIn1MbemCfWpQ" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">guide</a></span> with everything you\xe2\x80\x99ll need to know for a smooth transition. <br/><br/>As always \xe2\x80\x94 our technical team is available 24/7 via live chat or <span style="text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;color:#1155cc;"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/development/api-v1-to-v2-migration-guides/call-control&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1590777936749000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHQNNxgH4SnH0vAQiIn1MbemCfWpQ" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">lack</a></span> if you have any questions. <br/><br/><br/>- Product Release: <span style="text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;color:#1155cc;"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://telnyx.com/release-notes/twexit-api&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1590777936749000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGCQslT1s8cwrUGlx6SH_JK0uiz1A" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Twexit API</a></span><br/>- Portal Updates: <span style="text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;color:#1155cc;"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://telnyx.com/release-notes/portal-refresh-outbound-voice-profiles-and-call-control&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1590777936750000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHUMin-J9r1e7wMRcVVKbjJWNCE1A" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Outbound Voice Profiles and Call Control Applications</a></span><br/>- SMS <span style="text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;color:#1155cc;"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://telnyx.com/release-notes/sms-api-v2-field-deprecation&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1590777936750000&amp;usg=AFQjCNEfArz3AKCdS9Y2QzRaVT5FmE4hKQ" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">API V2</a></span> Field Deprecation<br/><br/>
```

I am currently using the "Publish to the web" option on the sheet and then using *urllib.request.urlopen().read()* in Python to get the html code.

```html
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTkMBs3ug1RMgDhi0oAWzLxk1CFXJQu6UkdFQIRVO6vdWS3sPtHvMh6Tecf-tt94nn7xuE2D-lwbzII/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true")
page_source = response.read()
```

Does anyone know a cleaner/better/easier way to get this html code using Python or using a Google sheets formula or script?

[Styled and Linked Text Within Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaFdy.png)